# Which LN implementation is better for developing Lightning apps in python(django framework)?

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

May be a noob question but I want to develop lapps in python(django framework for the web part)? Does the implementation make a difference? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All implementations have APIs against which you can easily program with any modern language. So I'd say it doesn't really matter.

However c-lightning ships with a python client called pyln or pylightning which also gives access to their low level plugin API which might be an additional reason for a python developer to select c-lightning